# Bash script that automatically kills processes when CPU/memory usage gets too high

Tags: bash, shell-script, memory, cpu, cpu-usage

I have created a script that kills processes if CPU and/or memory usage hits 80%. It creates a list of killed processes when this happens. What can I do to improve it?

```
while [ 1 ];
do 
echo
echo checking for run-away process ...

CPU_USAGE=$(uptime | cut -d"," -f4 | cut -d":" -f2 | cut -d" " -f2 | sed -e "s/\.//g")
CPU_USAGE_THRESHOLD=800
PROCESS=$(ps aux r)
TOPPROCESS=$(ps -eo pid -eo pcpu -eo command | sort -k 2 -r | grep -v PID | head -n 1)

if [ $CPU_USAGE -gt $CPU_USAGE_THRESHOLD] ; then
  kill -9 $(ps -eo pid | sort -k 1 -r | grep -v PID | head -n 1) #original
  kill -9 $(ps -eo pcpu | sort -k 1 -r | grep -v %CPU | head -n 1)
  kill -9 $TOPPROCESS
  echo system overloading!
  echo Top-most process killed $TOPPROCESS
      echo CPU USAGE is at $CPU_LOAD

else
    fi
    exit 0
    sleep 1;
    done
```

Comment: Have you tried running the script? `while [ 1 ]` makes me wonder how much CPU this script alone is going to consume. Also, 3 calls to `kill -9` in a script running constantly? [This gives me the chills ...](http://www.partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter)

Comment: Nice avatar anyway, @rahmu he got a `sleep 1` in the loop

Comment: First monday of the month and my PC is checking a (slow'ish) RAID6 set. CPU load easily peaks above 8 because it is constantly waiting for disk IO from this RAID set. Nothing wrong, system is still very responsive. Your script would kill my firefox which uses only 3.6% of the available 400%. Just saying you may be hunting for ghosts with this script. BTW: your system will not get damaged because of high load and when memory runs out, the kernel will do a semi-educated guess on which process(es) to kill.

Comment: Then kill process on based load will be fine or not ????

Comment: In my use case the killing is not desired.

Comment: are you familiar with the commands `cpulimit` and `timeout`?

Comment: You lack a white space between `CPU_USAGE_THRESHOLD` and `]` in `$CPU_USAGE_THRESHOLD]` as in `$CPU_USAGE_THRESHOLD ]`

Comment: So as to test this above script, how to create a running away process ?

Comment: The `PROCESS` variable is defined but never used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm *guessing* the problem you want to solve is that you have some process running on your box which sometimes misbehaves, and sits forever pegging a core.

The first thing you want to do is to attempt to fix the program that goes crazy. That is by far the best solution. I'm going to assume that isn't possible, or you need a quick kluge to keep your box running until its fixed.

You, at minimum, want to limit your script to only hit the one program you're concerned about. It'd be best if permissions limited your script like this (e.g., your script runs as user X, the only other thing running as X is the program).

Even better would be to use something like `ulimit -t` to limit the amount of total CPU time that the program can use. Similarly, if it consumes all memory, check `ulimit -v`. The kernel enforces these limits; see the `bash` manpage (it's a shell built-in) and the `setrlimit(2)` manpage for details.

If the problem isn't a process running amok, but is instead just too many processes running, then implement some form of locking to prevent more than X from running (or—this should be getting familiar—`ulimit -u`). You may also consider changing the scheduler priority of those processes (using `nice` or `renice`), or for even more drastic, using `sched_setscheduler` to change the policy to `SCHED_IDLE`.

If you need even more control, take a look a control groups (cgroups). Depending on the kernel you're running, you can actually limit the amount of CPU time, memory, I/O, etc. that a whole group of processes together consume. Control groups are quite flexible; they can likely do whatever you're trying to do, without any fragile kluges. The Arch Linux Wiki has [an intro to cgroups](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cgroups) that's worth reading, as is [Neil Brown's cgroups series](https://lwn.net/Articles/604609/) at LWN.

Answer (score 4):

Issues:

- When sorting numeric fields you probably want to use the `-n` option: `sort -nrk 2`. Otherwise a line with a `%CPU` value of 5.0 will end up higher than one with a value of 12.0.
- Depending on your `ps` implementation you might want to use the `--no-headers` option to get rid of the `grep -v`. That prevents you from discarding commands that contains `PID`.
- I guess instead of `echo CPU USAGE is at $CPU_LOAD`, you meant `echo CPU USAGE is at $CPU_USAGE`.
- I guess you forgot to remove the `exit 0` that you inserted during debugging(?).

Style:

- You might want to move the `CPU_USAGE_THRESHOLD=800` line to the beginning of the file, as this the most informative thing and is most likely to get changed even after your script is stable.
- You are repeating the `-e` option: `ps -eo pid -eo pcpu -eo command` is the same as `ps -eo pid -o pcpu -o command` (as is `ps -eo pid,pcpu,command`).
- There is an empty `else` clause. That always looks as if it should be handled, but was not for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a script, [kill-process](https://github.com/padosoft/kill-process), that kills some processes listed in an array, if CPU usage is greater than XX% for YY seconds or kill processes that's running more than ZZ seconds.

- You can set XX, YY, ZZ in the top of the file.
- You can use a ps or top for check processes.
- There's a dry run mode too, to check but not kill.
- In the end, the script sends an email if some processes were killed.

**NOTE:** Here is my repo on Github: https://github.com/padosoft/kill-process

Here's a screenshot:

[image: ss#1]

#### References

- [Original screenshot source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/padosoft/kill-process/master/resources/img/screen1.png)

#### Essential part of script (a code abstract for top command):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#max cpu % load
MAX_CPU=90
#max execution time for CPU percentage > MAX_CPU (in seconds 7200s=2h)
MAX_SEC=1800
#sort by cpu
SORTBY=9

#define a processes command name to check
declare -a KILLLIST
KILLLIST=("/usr/sbin/apache2" "/usr/bin/php5-cgi")

#iterate for each process to check in list
for PROCESS_TOCHECK in ${KILLLIST[*]}
do

    #retrive pid with top command order by SORTBY
    PID=$(top -bcSH -n 1 | grep $PROCESS_TOCHECK | sort -k $SORTBY -r | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')

    CPU=$(top -p $PID -bcSH -n 1 | grep $PROCESS_TOCHECK | sort -k $SORTBY -r | head -n 1 | awk '{print $9}')
    TIME_STR=$(top -p $PID -bcSH -n 1 | grep $PROCESS_TOCHECK | sort -k $SORTBY -r | head -n 1 | awk '{print $11}')

    # Decode the top CPU time format [dd-]hh:mm.ss.
    TIME_SEC=0
    IFS="-:" read c1 c2 c3 c4 <<< "$TIME_STR"

    #with top command time format is hh:mm.ss, so truncare seconds in c2
    c2=${c2%%.*}

    if [ -n "$c4" ]
    then
      TIME_SEC=$((10#$c4+60*(10#$c3+60*(10#$c2+24*10#$c1))))
    elif [ -n "$c3" ]
    then
      if [ "$CMD" = "ps" ]; then
        TIME_SEC=$((10#$c3+60*(10#$c2+60*10#$c1)))
      else
        TIME_SEC=$(((10#$c3*24)*60*60)+60*(10#$c2+60*10#$c1))             
      fi   
    else
      if [ "$CMD" = "ps" ]; then
        TIME_SEC=$((10#0+(10#$c2+60*10#$c1)))
      else
        TIME_SEC=$((10#0+60*(10#$c2+60*10#$c1)))
      fi
    fi

    #check if need to kill process
    if [ $CPU -gt $MAX_CPU ] && [ $TIME_SEC -gt $MAX_SEC ]; then
        kill -15 $PID
    fi

done
```

Usage:

```
bash killprocess.sh [dry|kill|--help] [top|ps] [cpu|time]
```

Comment: Seems `sort` should be `sort -k9nr`. Without `n`, will get ` 5.9` > `29.4`.

Comment: perfect - just needed little tune what I just pulled - thx

Answer (score 2):

Killing off processes which are using most CPU/memory is asking for trouble: Just look at what they are right now on your machine (here currently firefox, systemd (init), Xorg, gnome-terminal, a set of kernel threads, xemacs; none of which is dispensable). Look at how to tweak Linux' OOM-killer, for example [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html).

Also note that "memory used by the process" is a nebulous concept, as there are shared libraries, executables are shared, and even parts of data areas. One can come up with some number by charging each user with a fraction of the used space, but even adding that up really doesn't give "memory used" (even less "memory freed if the process goes away", the parts shared stay behind).